# How to bind selected item of Listview of unknown class to property

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, ms-access, data-binding

I have a Listview binded with an access database file and I'm trying ti bind the selected item to `SelectedEmployee` property.

```
<ListView x:Name="ListEmployee" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Employee ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Employee Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

When I've searched for solutions for this, the class of the items in the list are the same with the property being binded to. My problem is I don't know what is the class that makes up the items in the list.

Currently, this is how I fill the list:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
string cmd = "SELECT ID, FullName FROM Employees";
OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, connectionString);
Adapter.Fill(Data, "Employees");
ListEmployee.DataContext = Data;
```

And the class I'm using for the `SelectedEmployee` is:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

I've already tested if the `ListEmployee.SelectedItem is SelectedEmployee` and it's returning false and I can't find a way how can I create a class that matches the same type of the one from the List

So my problem is how can I bind the Selected Item yet not knowing the class that makes up the SelectedItem. Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: The DataContext of the ListView (or of one of its parent elements) should be set to a so-called view model object, which is an instance of a class with (at least) two properties, one collection-type property that holds the list of all Employees, and one property for the selected employee. You may search the web for "MVVM".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `Adapter.Fill` is creating a `Dataset`, which contains tables and `DataRows`. So the selectedItem will be a DataRow.

What I'd do is to create a list of Employee objects from your dataset, and bind to that:

```
Adapter.Fill(Data, "Employees");
var employees = new List<Employee>();
foreach(var row in Data.Tables[1].Rows)
{
    var employee = new Employee();
    employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"].ToString());
    employee.FullName = row["FullName"].ToString();
    employees.Add(employee);
}
ListEmployee.DataContext = employees;
```

This way, `SelectedItem` will be an employee object.

If you find yourself doing this a lot, I recommend using Entity Framework to handle all the tedious database stuff.

Comment: When you set the DataContext to a `List<Employee>`, the ItemsSource Binding would be `{Binding}`, but there would be no way to also bind SelectedItem. You actually need a view model class.